# How could I catch an exception from the default initialization of members in a constructor?

Tags: c++

In my constructor, I have to initialize the _socket.
But initializing the socket can throw an exception.
How can I catch and process the exception ?

Thanks !
Here my code:

```
tftp_server::tftp_server(unsigned short port_number)
: _socket(_io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port_number))
{    
    //...
}
```

Comment: good reading: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm

Comment: Possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160147/catching-exceptions-from-a-constructors-initializer-list

Comment: Good question despite it being a duplicate. The duplicate is better than my answer; which I've withdrawn.

Comment: Thanks Bryan Chen, it's exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to stackoverflown. Should I delete my question for being a duplicate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function try block.

```
tftp_server::tftp_server(unsigned short port_number)
try 
    : _socket(_io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port_number))
{    
    //...
}
catch(...)
{

}
```

But, to quote The Herb Sutter ([GotW 66](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm)):

> if the catch block does not throw (either rethrow the original
>   exception, or throw something new), and control reaches the end of the
>   catch block of a constructor or destructor, then the original
>   exception is automatically rethrown.

In other words (also Sutter)

> the only (repeat only) possible use for a constructor
>   function-try-block is to translate an exception thrown from a base or
>   member subobject

In summary: you *can* do that, but there's usually no point.

Answer (score 1):

See code below:

```
tftp_server::tftp_server(unsigned short port_number)
try : _socket(_io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port_number))
{    
    // Do your stuff
}
catch(...)
{
  // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: There is no way to "handle" a constructor exception. All you can do here is log failure.

Comment: The exception will still leave the constructor - there's no way to prevent that. This construct is only useful for logging, or if you have a badly-designed member that needs some kind of manual clean-up if initialisation fails, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Yes DevSolar, it's what I want to do (log error). Thanks !