# catch the exception from class member initialization "in-place"

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a class with a `std::regex` member:

```
class aaa {
    std::regex re {"aaabbb"};
public:
    aaa() {}
   ...
};
```

The `std::regex` can throw a `std::regex_error` if the string passed in is not a valid regular expression. Is there a technique in C++11/14 to catch this exception within the class?

similar to this:

```
class aaa {
    std::regex re;
public:
    aaa() 
    try 
       : re("aaabbb") {
    }
    catch(...) {
    }
};
```

Comment: And what is wrong with the latter method? That is a [perfectly acceptable way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160147/catching-exceptions-from-a-constructors-initializer-list) to catch the exception.

Comment: @CoryKramer It is not the member initializer he is looking for.

Comment: second way is acceptable, I just want to understand - new standards allows an initialization in member declaration but doesn't do any steps for exception handling for this way?

Comment: @amigo421: You can log the exception, and/or throw some other exception. Isn't that enough? Would you like to *ignore* any failure and just carry on? That's the approach used in many scripting languages as well as e.g. the Windows Graphics Device Interface, but it's not common in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually can not catch an exception without a rethrow (which is implicit), if an exception occurs in the initializer list:

```
include <stdexcept>

struct E { E(int) { throw std::runtime_error("E"); } };
class A {
    E e {1};
public:
    A()
    try
    {}
    catch(...) {
        std::cout << "Exception" << std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
Exception
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  E
Aborted
```

However, you can catch it, even without mentioning the member in the initializer list.

Hence, you may have an exception safe initialization of the member and handle exception critical assignment/initialization inside the constructors body (as other (deleted) answers suggested).

Comment: do you mean that exception during the initialization in place of declaration anyway will be catched up in ctor like you wrote? let me check, I can't believe in this

Comment: for the case of the processing in ctor body, your class E should have default ctor (for declaring this as a memeber of A) , but - if default ctor of E exists with the same code  - throws the exception, this can't be completely catched up in A ctor body and rethrowed again

Comment: @amigo421 If a member has not a non-throwing constructor, bad luck ;-(

Comment: seems the deleted answer (yes, I saw this, and didn't understand why the shared_ptr was used there) showed the only right way for such cases: using shared_ptr for declaring members with possible exceptions in ctors

Comment: @amigo421 the shared pointer is overkill - just have an empty regex

Answer (score 1):

There might be a fancier way to do it, but I'd just have `std::regex re;` be declared as a class member variable, and try to initialize it in the default and/or other constructors. Then you could handle the exception within the constructor.